# PHPUnit testing framework version 6 or greater is required when running on PHP 7.2 or greater

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, drupal-8, phpunit

Within a Drupal 8 project I try to run PHPUnit tests with the following command:

```
cd htdocs/core
../../vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite=unit
```

I get the following error:

```
PHPUnit testing framework version 6 or greater is required when running on PHP 7.2 or greater. Run the command 'composer run-script drupal-phpunit-upgrade' in order to fix this.
```

When I run the following command:

```
composer run-script drupal-phpunit-upgrade
```

I get the following error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                      
Script "drupal-phpunit-upgrade" is not defined in this package  
run-script [--timeout TIMEOUT] [--dev] [--no-dev] [-l|--list] [--] [<script>] [<args>]...
```

I check my PHP version with `php --version` and get the following info:

```
PHP 7.2.6-1+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)
```

I check my PHPUnit version with `phpunit --version` and get the following info:

```
PHPUnit 6.5.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

My PHPUnit testing version meets the requirement on PHP 7.2 in my OS. I don't know why I get that error related to the PHPUnit testing version. And when I run the composer run-script as shown in the error, I get another error which is the dead end way for me. How can I fix this? or where should I focus on?

Comment: "I check my PHPUnit version" that may not be the PHPUnit version Drupal uses. For that run `composer show` to see the versions used in the project.

Comment: I ran `composer show` within the root directory of my Drupal 8 project and get a list of package/library/component. I don't know exactly what  they are but no any version.

Comment: when I run `composer show` it lists package/version/short info. Not sure why it doesn't do that for you.

Comment: I get this format `phpunit/phpunit` and `phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects`. But you have a good clue. I updated the phpunit version in composer.json to `"phpunit/phpunit": "6.*",` and ran `composer install`. I check the phpunit version on the Settings window of PHPStorm and it changed from `4.8.*` to `6.5.8`. I run `../../vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite=unit ` again and still get that error.

Comment: What does `../../vendor/bin/phpunit --version` give you?

Comment: It is too late to answer your question because I just removed PHP7.2 and run everything on PHP7.1 which does not require PHPUnit 6.* anymore. On PHP7.1 I get PHPUnit 4.8.36 with `../../vendor/bin/phpunit --version`.

Comment: On another note, `composer run-script drupal-phpunit-upgrade` requires Drupal 8.5+. But you could just run the underlying command by yourself.